# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS freezes after login

Tags: nvidia, kernel, 18.04, freeze

So as soon as I log in, a few seconds later Ubuntu freezes. I booted with a live CD and checked `var/crash/` and found out the following report:

```
ProblemType: KernelOops
Annotation: Your system might become unstable now and might need to be restarted.
Date: Fri Sep 14 10:30:16 2018
Failure: oops
OopsText:
 watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 23s! [kworker/0:1:37]
 Modules linked in: rfcomm nouveau bnep mxm_wmi ttm nls_iso8859_1 arc4 snd_soc_skl snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_compress snd_hda_codec_generic ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm intel_wmi_thunderbolt uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp ath10k_pci ath10k_core videodev media ath rtsx_usb_ms memstick kvm mac80211 snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth snd_seq_device snd_timer cfg80211 ecdh_generic snd irqbypass intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf mei_me mei joydev input_leds serio_raw soundcore intel_pch_thermal
  ideapad_laptop sparse_keymap shpchp tpm_crb mac_hid wmi acpi_pad sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 algif_skcipher af_alg dm_crypt hid_generic rtsx_usb_sdmmc usbhid hid rtsx_usb crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc i915 aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd psmouse i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops drm r8169 ahci ipmi_devintf libahci ipmi_msghandler mii video
 CPU: 0 PID: 37 Comm: kworker/0:1 Tainted: G        W    L   4.15.0-33-generic #36-Ubuntu
 Hardware name: LENOVO 80SM/Toronto 5A2, BIOS 0XCN37WW 10/03/2016
 Workqueue: events netstamp_clear
 RIP: 0010:smp_call_function_many+0x22c/0x250
 RSP: 0018:ffffae09c0dfbd00 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff11
 RAX: 0000000000000001 RBX: ffff8ca9434238c0 RCX: 0000000000000003
 RDX: ffff8ca9434a7e40 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffff8ca93a822548
 RBP: ffffae09c0dfbd38 R08: ffffffffffffffff R09: 000000000000000e
 R10: ffffeec3c9d41100 R11: 0000000000000d00 R12: 0000000000000004
 R13: 0000000000023880 R14: ffffffffa9c35170 R15: 0000000000000000
 FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8ca943400000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
 CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
 CR2: 00007f9eb4ba84c0 CR3: 000000015900a006 CR4: 00000000003606f0
 Call Trace:

Package: linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic 4.15.0-33.36
SourcePackage: linux
Tags: kernel-oops
Uname: Linux 4.15.0-33-generic x86_64
```

Before too I used to get the same error but at random, not necessarily after login. After googling I found out that it could be a graphics driver issue, so I replaced the existing default driver with closed source Nvidia driver, but the problem persists.

I freshly installed Ubuntu and upgraded. And after using it for a day or so this problem comes up again.

I don't think it's a hardware issue as the machine works fine when booted with a Live CD, or on Windows.

`Alt` + `PrtSc` + `REISUB` doesn't work either.

Comment: I also get different CPU #s different time.